# gvisPieChart tooltip - only percentage

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, googlevis

In this example, I want a tooltip that shows only the percentage, omitting the absolute value.

```
a<-c('option1','option2','option3')
b<-c(35,80,10)
data<-data.frame(a,b)

myplot<-gvisPieChart(data,options=list(title='Example',width=1000, height=500))

plot(myplot)
```

At https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart
I found this:

[image]

But I do not know how and if it´s possible to adapt to googleVis.

Thanks in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an option `tooltip = "{text:'percentage'}"`

```
library(googleVis)
a<-c('option1','option2','option3')
b<-c(35,80,10)
data<-data.frame(a,b)

myplot<-gvisPieChart(data,options=list(title='Example',width=1000, height=500
                                       , tooltip = "{text:'percentage'}"))

plot(myplot)
```

[image]